# Cannot place a wallsign or edit its text

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to place and edit a wall-sign facing west. I have been so far unsuccessful at both orienting the sign correctly and editing its text. My code simply doesn't do anything.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void Generate(Location location)
{
    location.getBlock().getState().setType(material);
    Block signBlock = location.getBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.WEST);
    signBlock.setType(Material.OAK_WALL_SIGN);
    BlockState signState = signBlock.getState();
    Sign sign = (Sign) signState;
    org.bukkit.material.Sign matSign = new org.bukkit.material.Sign(Material.OAK_WALL_SIGN);
    matSign.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.WEST);
    sign.setData(matSign);
    sign.setLine(0, name().replaceAll("_", " "));
    sign.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code resolved the issue:

```
public void Generate(Location location)
{
    location.getBlock().getState().setType(material);
    Block block = location.getBlock().getLocation().add(-1, 0, 0).getBlock();
    block.setType(Material.OAK_WALL_SIGN);
    Sign sign = (Sign) block.getState();
    Directional wallSignData = (Directional) sign.getBlockData();
    wallSignData.setFacing(BlockFace.WEST);
    sign.setBlockData(wallSignData);
    sign.setLine(0, name().replaceAll("_", " "));
    sign.update();
}
```